# ¿Es correcto saludarlos en el día del programador en Meta?

Tags: discusión

Siendo hoy el día 1111 1111 (contando desde 0*), me gustaría poder saludarlos por el Día del Programador (al menos por acá en Meta).

¿Es válido poner el saludo como pregunta?

De todas formas tengan un Muy Feliz Día del Programador.

*1/1 es el índice 0 del array año (si, hasta para nuestras celebraciones somos raros).

Comment: Yo creería que sí. Feliz día a ti también :)

Comment: Holi! Felicidades a todos los picateclas!

Comment: eeeepa! feliz día hermanos :D

Answer (score 6):

```
01000110 01100101 01101100 01101001 01111010 00100000 01100100 11101101 
01100001 00100000 01100100 01100101 01101100 00100000 01110000 01110010 
01101111 01100111 01110010 01100001 01101101 01100001 01100100 01101111 
01110010 00100000 01100001 00100000 01110100 01101111 01100100 01101111 
01110011 00101110
```

Answer (score -2):

Dependiendo del sistema, el resultado cambia. Por ejemplo, hice un código en javascript, la fecha termina siendo otra.

```js
var fecha_1 = new Date("01/01/2016").getTime()
var bit34anterior = Math.pow(2,32)-1
var fecha_2 = new Date(fecha_1+bit34anterior)
var día = fecha_2.getDate()
var mes = fecha_2.getMonth()+1
document.write(día+"/"+mes)
```

La respuesta es 19 de Febrero. Lo hago así, elevando 2^32 para que sea en todos los años igual y que no dependa de si el año es bisiesto.

Comment: Tu código tiene un bug. Imprime el año... el día es el 0b11111111, y no 2^34-1

Comment: @jachguate En la respuesta de toledano, pero en el mío no.

Comment: ¿Imprimiste el año?

Comment: @jachguate No hace falta, ya que es el día situado en el año, que puede ser cualquiera. El día del programador puede variar si el año es bisiesto.

Comment: Cualquier día está situado en "un año", pero creo que se supone que si quieres celebrar el día del programador del año 2016, el día de la celebración esté dentro del año 2016. ¿no es así?

Comment: @jachguate Así es.

Comment: jajaja, ok, solo que tu rutina lo deja en un año un poco lejano, no en el mismo. No se si es un bug o así es la especificación de tu programa, pero tampoco nos vamos a pelear por eso, jajajaja.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/563406/5290909

Answer (score -3):

Si escribo en Python `0b11111111` el resultado es 255.

```python
>>> 0b11111111
255
```

El día 255 **de este año** fue el 11 de septiembre, o sea, ayer. Hoy es el día 256, o sea `10 000 000`.

```python
>>> bin(256)
'0b100000000'
```

Así que no es válido ;)

Comment: La cuenta es desde 0 (cero) ;-P [ver](http://www.programmerday.info/)